# How can I map this join data in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two API Data I am using. I am trying to map the data as list item. I am also trying to map the correct logo for the correct item using **productCode** as a matching point. How can I achieve this? I have attached my code below. Each item must have the logo, the amount, and productCode. Please if there is also a better way to merge the two API, I would be happy to learn....

```
export default function App() {

  const [Alldata, setAlldata] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // GET request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
    fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/rows/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setAlldata(json));
    // empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like componentDidMount in classes)
  }, []);

  const token = "TOKEN HERE";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResult(json));
  }, []);

  const mainDATA = {result, Alldata};
  console.log(mainDATA);


  return (
    <div>App</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do these two APIs relate to one another? In other words, how does the data they fetch and get stored in state relate? Are they a 1-to-1 relation and you just need to merge two arrays? Do you need to look up data from one array in the other? What have you tried already on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(result.result);
  });
```

.. is likely to cause an infinite loop as it'll run on every render. Calling setProducts will queue a new render, that'll re-run useEffect etc, that'll queue a new render etc.

I think you can leave out this useEffect and simply use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setProducts(json?.result));
  }, []);
```

.. to write direct to the `products` state.

Then (assuming that products is an array, and you have a component ProductItem that can render it) you'd write something like:

```
return (
<div>
{ products.map( product => <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product}/> ) }
</div>
  )
```

Comment: how do i map the data?

Comment: I'm not sure what's in your data, but in the JSX part you'd write something like: { products.map(product => <div key={product.id}>YOUR PRODUCT COMPONENT HERE</div>}

Comment: Oh, I have updated the code. I need to map data inside mainDATA. There are two objects inside it. It is the combine data from the two APIs.

mainDATA = {results, AllData}.

I want to map inside mainDATA. Then fetch items inside the two items in it. For example.

<p>Code: {mainDATA.results.productCode}</p>
<img>Img: {mainDATA.AllData.data.attributes.logo}</img>


I hope it make sense

Comment: This is what I have tried.

    <div>{mainDATA.map( item => 
      <p >{mainDATA.Alldata.data.attributes.Country}</p>
      )}
      
      </div>`